# Tailwind - css - flex placement

Tags: flexbox, tailwind-css

I have a footer with some list items and then some social media icons. I want to move the social media items to the right of the footer. How would I achieve this? I have been playing around with flex but nothing is working yet.

```
  <div className="mx-20 mb-20">
    <Divider style={{ background: '#5E5E5E96' }} orientation="horizontal" />
    <div className="mt-8 w-full flex">
      <div>
        <ul className="flex">
          <span className="ml-8 mr-20">
            <li>&copy;2022 {name}</li>
          </span>
          <span className="flex space-x-20">
            <li>Cookie Policy</li>
            <li>Refund Policy</li>
            <li>Privacy Policy</li>
            <li>Terms & Conditions</li>
          </span>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="icons flex">
        <img src={InstagramIcon} alt="Instagram icon" />
        <img src={FacebookIcon} alt="Facebook icon" />
        <img src={TwitterIcon} alt="Twitter icon" />
        <img src={Linkedin} alt="Linkedin icon" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

So I want the icons to be the same distance from the right as the first list item is from the left.
[image]

Comment: add `ml-auto` to `<div className="icons flex">` as a variant. Or `justify-between` for `<div className="mt-8 w-full flex">`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in multiple ways:

1. add `justify-between`
2. add `ml-auto` to the item you want to move.

In both cases, your flex container has to be 100% wide `w-full`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `justify-between` or `justify-evenly` on the outer most div that wraps both the list and the icons.

Below is the code

```
<div className="mx-20 mb-20">
    <Divider style={{ background: '#5E5E5E96' }} orientation="horizontal" />
    <div className="mt-8 w-full flex items-center justify-between">
      <div>
        <ul className="flex">
          <span className="ml-8 mr-20">
            <li>&copy;2022 {name}</li>
          </span>
          <span className="flex space-x-20">
            <li>Cookie Policy</li>
            <li>Refund Policy</li>
            <li>Privacy Policy</li>
            <li>Terms & Conditions</li>
          </span>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="icons flex">
        <img src={InstagramIcon} alt="Instagram icon" />
        <img src={FacebookIcon} alt="Facebook icon" />
        <img src={TwitterIcon} alt="Twitter icon" />
        <img src={Linkedin} alt="Linkedin icon" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> `items-center` is align them vertically